# Safari smart app banner open only AppStore instead of installed app - iOS

Tags: ios, safari, smart-app-banner

The Meta tag is added in the html as below with correct and actual values

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

The web page on mobile browser successfully shows the prompt. When I tap 'Open', it always open the AppStore instead opening the app. Any help would be appreciated.